# Sqlite where query in Python on integer value field not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to query a SQLite database for the rows that satisfy the condition           `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE 'FirstPacketTime' > 1570680300")`.

I have looked through multiple stackoverflow questions and other online resources. In this case the FirstPacketTime db field is defined as an integer datatype (datetime in seconds). The row results are also coming back as integers, however the row data contains rows where the FirstPacketTime values are clearly less than the value shown above. Changing the greater than to an equal or less than ends up with no query results. What am I missing here? I have done queries before with python against MySQL databases with no issue.

### Database schema

- (0, 'FirstPacketTime', 'integer', 0, None, 0)
- (1, 'SourceIP', 'text', 0, None, 0)
- (2, 'SourcePort', 'integer', 0, None, 0)
- (3, 'DestinationIP', 'text', 0, None, 0)
- (4, 'DestinationPort', 'integer', 0, None, 0)
- (5, 'Protocol', 'text', 0, None, 0)
- (6, 'TotalBytes', 'integer', 0, None, 0)
- (7, 'TotalPackets', 'integer', 0, None, 0)

### Query results - first 10 records

- (1570676279, '19.116.151.212', 9876, '19.116.0.157', 53299, 'tcp_ip', 56, 1)
- (1570676279, '19.116.151.212', 9876, '19.116.0.157', 53301, 'tcp_ip', 56, 1)
- (1570650779, '19.116.1.36', 53497, '19.116.160.133', 102, 'tcp_ip', 67799, 696)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.20', 3139, '19.116.29.147', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.20', 3479, '19.116.29.189', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.17', 3843, '19.116.29.33', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.24', 2398, '19.116.29.6', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.20', 3206, '19.116.29.159', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.20', 3161, '19.116.29.151', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)
- (1570676339, '19.116.89.15', 1082, '19.116.0.16', 445, 'tcp_ip', 96, 2)

### Code

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE 'FirstPacketTime' > 1570680300")
rows = cur.fetchmany(10)
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes: `SELECT * FROM data WHERE FirstPacketTime > 1570680300`

Comment: I tried that and ended up with no results.

Comment: Do you have any rows that you'd expect to be returned?

Comment: To add to forpas's comment, see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html.  Single quotes delimit strings, not database object names.

Comment: I do have data that I expect to be returned. I have also tried setting the criteria to return the FirstPacketTime equal to the value 1570676279 (first one shown above in the query results) and get nothing back. removing the single quotes from the fieldname results in nothing coming back.

Comment: Make a fiddle with a sample of your data and post it.

Comment: If you look at the database schema shown above the fieldnames have single quotes. I have seen documentation showing using and not using the single quotes for python queries, so have tried both and I only get results if I use them.

Comment: In regards to the single quotes:  You shared no code and the link I shared was from official docs.  We can't interpret what you are doing if you don't shared actual python code with more detail.  As it is, it makes no sense why single quotes would be necessary... and you are obviously not getting correct results anyway, so it's not a good argument to keep using single-quotes around column names.

Comment: I don't have fiddle. I used the convert portion of the program located at https://github.com/rufuspollock/csv2sqlite/blob/master/csv2sqlite.py. There are over 12 million records in the resulting database file. The headers are coming from the first line in a csv file.

Comment: You can get the table DDL (CREATE TABLE) statement by executing `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'data'`

Comment: If the column names actually contain single quotes then try this: `SELECT * FROM data WHERE ['FirstPacketTime'] > 1570680300`

Comment: I used `dbfields = cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info('data')").fetchall()` to obtain the database schema shown above. I'm not getting anything with the Select statement.

Comment: forpas, the Select statement with the brackets gave me an operational error saying that there is no such column as 'FirstPacketTime'. So the field name does not actually contain the single quotes. This issue has me really scratching my head as to why it won't work...

Comment: So I just tried a query using `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE SourceIP = '19.116.151.212'")` and got the results I would expect. So it must have something to do with how the integer is being interpreted. I did not use the single quotes for the fieldname.

Comment: Now I just tried it with the FirstPacketTime without single quotes and equal to a value in the results and it worked! So it must be a data issue. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Lessons learned: query using database field without single quotes and make sure you have the data you are looking for in the database file. I had only loaded one of nine files into the database, so the data for the date I was looking for was not there!

Answer (score 2):

A sample db created

[image]

[image]

Below query was executed, and was able to get the records

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
print (c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE FirstPacketTime < 1570676280").fetchall())
print (c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE FirstPacketTime = 1570676279").fetchall())
print (c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE FirstPacketTime = 1570676339").fetchall())

[(1570676279, '19.116.151.212', 9876)]
[(1570676279, '19.116.151.212', 9876)]
[(1570676339, '19.116.89.20', 3139)]
```

What i did is Removed the single quotes.

Also , initially it didnt appear for me , because i had not committed the data to database.

Once the data was commited to the database , i was able to get the output